# moving an element in 2d array with arrow keys and having border restricting movement

Tags: c#, arrays

I dont know if this has been answered before but how would I move an element in 2d array with arrow keys? say something like this and having it not move if it is not possible as in the image displayed 0 can swap and go up, down, left and right but the next move you are restricted to just three options as up,down and left only

New to c# so if there are helpful examples online about my problem just post them down the comment

[image]

```
using System;

namespace moveElement
{
    public class move
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[,] arr = { { 9, 1, 4 }, { 5, 0, 3 }, { 6, 8, 2 } };
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                        {
                            Console.Write(arr[i, j] + " ");
                        }

                        Console.WriteLine();
                    }
        }
    }
}
```

Took what was suggested and made it work somehow like this

```
            ConsoleKeyInfo info = Console.ReadKey();
            if (info.Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow)
            {
                int temp = arr[1, 1];
                arr[1, 1] = arr[1, 2];
                arr[1, 2] = temp;
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(arr[i, j] + " ");

                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();

                }

            }
```

After working on the code for sometime I get error `"use of unassigned local variable x and y"` on line 41(`y`) and 47(`x`) I have completed most of the problem but stuck on this error

```
using System;

namespace moveElement
{
    public class move
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int x, y;
            int[,] arr = { { 0, 1, 4 }, { 3, 9, 5 }, { 6, 8, 2 } };
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(arr[i, j] + " ");
```

Solved the problem by giving `x` and `y` a value of `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something similar to the answer of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375233/swap-elements-in-a-2d-array-c-sharp) where you take the variable of position 1, put it in a temp variable, then set position 1 to the value of position 2 and finally set the value of position 2 to what is in the temp variable:

```
var t = a;
a = b;
b = t;
```

To actually figure out if you can move in a specific direction, you will need to check if you are at a boundary, for example, the boundaries would be (where i is any valid position):

```
arr[0, i]
arr[arr.getLength(0)-1, i]
arr[i, 0]
arr[i, arr.getLength(1)-1]
```

if your current position is the same as one of those, you will need to add some conditions so that you cant move in a specific direction, for example, if you have arr[0, i], you cannot move up one as it will then go to arr[-1, i] which does not exist.

I would suggest reading up on the Array.getLength(Int32 dimension) [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.getlength?view=netframework-4.8) for finding the boundaries (it essentially gets the length of the array at a specified dimension)

Comment: I was able to solve my problem huge thanks for the suggestions